# How can i optimize this oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm working with oracle 11g and we have a problem, well, this query takes forever to execute, the main table tbl_inc has about 17 million records, is there any way i can improve this query?
i can't add indexes, i don't have privileges for that.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TBL_INC INC LEFT JOIN TBL_PDS P ON INC.SID = P.TRX
INNER JOIN TBL_ASTS ASTS ON ASTS.CODE = INC.CODE AND ASTS.MIT 
= INC.MIT AND ASTS.OPE_PROD = 3
WHERE (INC.INC_DATE -1) >= to_date('29/10/20', 'DD/MM/YY')
AND INC.INC_DATE - 1  <= to_date('05/11/20', 'DD/MM/YY')
AND INC.OPE = 50 AND SUBSTR(INC.CARD_NMBR, 1, 6) = 123456 
AND INC.MIT='05' AND INC.CODE='00';
```

thanks

Comment: _I can't add indexes_ - I would have thought that ensuring the criteria columns were indexed would immediately improve the speed of the query!

Comment: If you want to find out why it is slow, put a `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` before the statement.

Comment: @dratenik i did, it shows the TBL_ASTS is making a full scan, i understand that can be avoided with indexes, but i don't have privileges to create them

Comment: So in the absence of an index or partitioning it sounds as though you will inevitably have to read the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would rewrite this so the `where` clause does not have expressions on the columns:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM TBL_INC INC LEFT JOIN
     TBL_PDS P
     ON INC.SID = P.TRX INNER JOIN
     TBL_ASTS ASTS
     ON ASTS.CODE = INC.CODE AND
        ASTS.MIT = INC.MIT AND
        ASTS.OPE_PROD = 3
WHERE INC.INC_DATE >= to_date('29/10/20', 'DD/MM/YY') + interval '1 day' AND
AND INC.INC_DATE - 1  <= to_date('05/11/20', 'DD/MM/YY') + interval '1 day' AND
      INC.OPE = 50 AND
      INC.CARD_NMBR  LIKE '123456%' AND
      INC.MIT = '05' AND INC.CODE = '00';
```

Then for this query, you want an index on:  `TBL_INC(MIT, CODE, OPE, INC_DATE, CARD_NMBR)`.  I am guessing that you have indexes on the `JOIN` keys used in the other tables, but those would be `TBL_PDS(TRX)` and `TBL_ASTS(CODE< MIT, OPE_PROD)`.

Answer (score -1):

It is a very good practice to reduce the number of the rows from the join, rather that apply a 'where' condition to the end

```
SELECT count(1) FROM TBL_INC INC 
INNER JOIN TBL_ASTS ASTS 
 ON ASTS.CODE = INC.CODE
 AND ASTS.MIT = INC.MIT
 AND ASTS.OPE_PROD = 3
 AND INC.OPE = 50
 AND SUBSTR(INC.CARD_NMBR, 1, 6) = 123456 
 AND INC.MIT='05' 
 AND INC.CODE='00'
 AND (INC.INC_DATE -1) >=  to_date('29/10/20', 'DD/MM/YY')
 AND INC.INC_DATE - 1  <= to_date('05/11/20', 'DD/MM/YY')
LEFT JOIN 
TBL_PDS P 
ON INC.SID = P.TRX
```

Comment: Writing filter conditions in the `join` clause does not affect the number of rows joined. Also, the standard expression for counting in SQL is `count(*)`, although things like `count('Dracula')` etc will work if you really must.